# Mysql - How do I order results by alternating (1,2,3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,) rows, is it possible?

Tags: sql, mysql, ranking

I want to order my results by client 1, 2, 3, then again client 1, 2, 3, and so on.

Is there a way to do this without using a for loop or making three separate queries? Not only that, but I am working with paginated data so it needs to return x results, but consistently.

Any ideas? GROUP BY maybe?

```
client_id  project_id  project_name  
---------- ----------  ------------
 1         42          project abc
 2         49          project xyz
 3         41          project 123
 1         22          project apple
 2         29          project orange
 3         21          project banana
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the output you're looking for?

Comment: Is there some column (or col combination) that determines the order for all rows belonging to one client? If so, it may be possible with ORDER BY, and some tinkering. please post some raw sample data and th desired output.

re. the pagination: what do you want to do in case the 3rd group of rows does contain a row for client 1 and client 3, but not client 2? 

re GROUP BY: I don't see how that could help, GROUP BY essentially flattens a collection of rows, i think your problem is primarily a sorting problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT x.client_id, 
       x.project_id,
       x.project_name
  FROM (SELECT t.client_id,
               t.project_id,
               t.project_name,
               CASE
                 WHEN @client_id != t.client_id THEN @rownum := 0
                 WHEN @client_id = t.client_id THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
                 ELSE @rownum 
               END AS rank,
               @client_id := t.client_id
          FROM TABLE t,
               (SELECT @rownum := 0, @client_id
      ORDER BY t.client_id) r) x
ORDER BY x.rank, x.client_id
```

MySQL doesn't have any ranking functionality, but luckily you can use variables.  The key was resetting the @rownum value when the client_id doesn't match the previous client_id - the ORDER BY in the subquery is to ensure that clients are in order.

Comment: This is awesome, I read the question and got did some googling and was going to type up a much jankier solution when I luckily saw this.  I don't think you need the "ELSE @rownum", but other than that nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

Why not `ORDER BY id`?

Comment: well i need to order by client id alternating
client 1, then client 2, then client 3, repeat

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` is not going to be helpful.  Whether this is possible is going to depend a lot on your data.  Basically you would need a convoluted `ORDER BY` that hacked something together based on other values.

For instance, using the example data you gave, you could use:

```
ORDER BY FLOOR(project_id / 10), client_id
```

This is unlikely to be useful on your real data but it gives the idea that you would need to take a separate field, make some subsets of that data be equivalent for the purpose of sorting (in this case, everything with the same 10s value) and the have a secondary sort on client_id.

Although it depends a lot on the final formula, something like this should be a relatively stable sort, so adding pagination, such as via

```
LIMIT 10, 10
```

should return consistent results.

Of course, doing this means you get no benefits from having indexes so if you have a lot of rows, it will end up being slower than doing something with loops/separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I read the question wrong is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE client_id in (1, 2, 3)
ORDER by id, client_id
```

Comment: The `id` values aren't shared with any group of `client_id`s

Comment: not quite, i need the return results to be ordered alternating
1, 2, 3 then again 1, 2, 3 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something to be done client-side.