# Fix query that orders MYSQL results by alternating 1,2,3 - 1,2,3 - 1,2,3

Tags: mysql

I have asked a question before about ordering MYSQL results by alternating (1,2,3 - 1,2,3 - 1,2,3) rows and I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959414/mysql-how-do-i-order-results-by-alternating-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-rows-i)

I tried to apply the code to my situation and this is what I have got:

```
SELECT 
x.id, 
x.pic0,
x.bio,
x.bio2,
x.site,
x.url,
x.applet
FROM 
(SELECT 
t.id, 
t.pic0,
t.bio,
t.bio2,
t.site,
t.url,
t.applet
CASE
WHEN @site != t.site THEN @rownum := 0
WHEN @site = t.site THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
ELSE @rownum
END AS rank,
@site := t.site
FROM ".$table." t,
(SELECT @rownum := 0, @site ORDER BY t.site) r) x 
ORDER BY x.rank, x.site
```

This is the MYSQL error I am getting - server is using MYSQL 5.1

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN @site != t.site THEN @rownum := 0 WHEN @site = t.site THEN @rownum :' at line 18
```

1. I am a total newb and this query, I cannot even begin to understand it :) so I don't have the slightest idea on what is wrong with it.
2. How to add WHERE conditions to this query?

   WHERE bio LIKE 'value' and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a `,`

```
t.applet , CASE WHEN @site ...
         ^................................here
```

add the `where` here:

```
FROM ".$table." t,
(SELECT @rownum := 0, @site ORDER BY t.site) r) x 

WHERE bio LIKE 'value'

ORDER BY x.rank, x.site
```

Comment: Ty, that fixed a part, now I get this: #1109 - Unknown table 't' in order clause

Comment: remove `ORDER BY t.site` since `@site` is just 1 record anyway

Comment: or should it be `@site := t.site`?

Comment: I just adapted this query and I do not understand it, so in a way I was silly to ask for someone to fix something I do not understand myself. Ty for trying