# Mysql How to sort rows to appear like this (e.g. 1 2 1 2 )

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a column Word with values A and B. For example:

```
Row Word
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   B
5   B
6   B
```

I want to sort them like this in MySql:

```
Row Word
1   A
2   B
3   A
4   B
5   A
6   B
```

if i use ms sql

```
SELECT Word FROM Test
ORDER BY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Word ORDER BY Word), Word
```

how to i write a code in mysql like this?

Comment: Include `show create table your_table;` and `select row, word from your_table;`. What have you already tried?

Comment: You need some way of uniquely identifying rows

Comment: dgijay Word Column datas are mixed like A B B A A B but I want to sort them like A B A B. One A then B then A ....

Comment: But what if values are `A B B A A B C C D` for example ? To receive and answer, you need to give more explanation about the input data and the sorting logic.

Comment: Since we are not getting replies to the comments for 7 hours now, I am voting to close this question as *Unclear what you're asking*

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in MySQL 8. My table is like this:

[image: Screenshot of table, 10 rows, 2 columns "ID" and "Word"]

My SQL code is

```
SELECT Word
    FROM test
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Word ORDER BY Word), Word;
```

So this table sorted like this:

[image: Screenshot of table, sorted]

i found a code in below but it is not correctly provides A B A B order.

```
SELECT 
    x.Word 
FROM
    (Select 
                t.Word,
                CASE
                    WHEN @word != t.Word THEN @rownum := 0
        WHEN @word = t.Word THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
        ELSE @rownum
                END AS rutbe,
                @word := t.Word
            From 
                test t, (SELECT @rownum := 0, @word ORDER BY @word) r
    ) x
ORDER BY x.rutbe, x.Word
```

Comment: You can't use `ORDER BY` in the traditional sense, you need to get creative. See this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959414/mysql-how-do-i-order-results-by-alternating-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-rows-i

Comment: thanks Wayne Phipps. I use the code in the link that given by you